# Does every point in a manifold has a open orientable neighborhood?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Even if a manifold $M$ is not orientable, does every point have an open orientable neighborhood?

This question comes up when I read a proof of Theorem 15.40, which shows the existence of orientation covering of a manifold in the J. M. Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.* In the proof, the author assumes that we can have an orientable open neighborhood for any point of the manifold.

By the definition of manifold, given atlas $\{(U,\phi)\}$ since $U$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, maybe it gives some orientation, but I cannot show it rigorously. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Each point has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You mean that since $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is orientable, so does $U$?

Comment: Yes. You can use the diffeomorphism to pull back a preferred orientation on $\mathbb R^n$ to $U$.

Comment: @BerniWaterman All right! Thank you :)

Comment: There are many ways to define an orientation. One can even define it in a purely topological setting, devoid of any differentiable structure. My guess is that you have seen the definition in terms of nowhere-vanishing top-dimensional differential forms, right ?

Comment: @BerniWaterman Yes. I've seen it but I didn't know that it is another definition; I just saw it as a theorem that if we had such nowhere-vanishing top-dimensional differential forms then the manifold is orientable.

Comment: Perfect. Then the only thing you have to verify in detail then is that the pullback of a nowhere-vanishing top-form under a diffeomorphism is again nowhere-vanishing. But that is straightforward.

Comment: @BerniWaterman Thank you very much :) I will definitely try to verify it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can simply use Lee's more basic definition. We only need to know that $p\in U$ for some chart $(U,x^i:1\le i\le n).$ Because in this case, we can give $U$ the pointwise orientation $\mathscr O$ determined by the vectors $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p:1\le i\le n,\ p\in U\}.$ Then by construction $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p:1\le i\le n\right)$ is a positively oriented basis for $T_pU$ at every point $p\in U$ and by definition, $\mathscr O$ is continuous, and so again, by definition, $\mathscr O$ is an orientation on $U.$

I think this approach has the benefit of making it clear that problems with orientability can only arise from incompatibility of the charts, where the Jacobian of at least one transition function fails to be positive.